# How to print object of type List<string> in C#

Tags: c#

I am new to c# and I want to print object which is of List type. How can I print this object and display list in console?
Below is my code:

```
class Program{
    public List<double> GetPowersOf2(int input)
    {
        var returnList = new List<double>();
        for (int i = 0; i < input + 1; i++)
        {
            returnList.Add(Math.Pow(2, i));
        }
         returnList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);//display list from method.
        return returnList;
    }
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        Console.WriteLine(p.GetPowersOf2(2));//not display list...
    }
}
```

It gives error: *System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Double]*
Please suggest solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not an error, that's what you told it to output. (Name of the class)

Comment: You already discovered that `returnList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine)` works. Why don't you try `p.GetPowersOf2(2).ForEach(Console.WriteLine)` then? Both are `List<double>` so what works for one should work for the other, no?

Answer (score 2):

Try a simple *Linq* and `Join` the outcome into a single `string`:

```
  // Let's use BigInteger instead of Double to represent 2's powers
  using System.Numerics;

  ...

  int input = 12;

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable
    .Range(0, input)
    .Select(index => BigInteger.Pow(2, index)));

  Console.Write(report);
```

Outcome:

```
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
1024
2048
```

Comment: Thanks ...its really helps me a lot

Comment: @Angad. If that answer helps you, why don't you accept it so other people can see what worked for you?  :-).

Answer (score 0):

```
var powers=p.GetPowersOf2(2);
foreach(double power in powers) Console.Writeline(power+", ");
```

The reason why your original code did not work is is because the default implementation of `.ToString()` is to simply print the name of class. Only in certain classes is this overridden.

If you want to change the default behavior of `.ToString` for your list you will have to derive a class from `List`.

```
    public class PrintableList<T> : List<T>
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            string result = "";
            foreach (T obj in this)
            {
                result += obj.ToString() + "\n";
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Use this in place of your list in your code, and your code will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq:

public class Program{

```
public List<double> GetPowersOf2(int input)
{
    var returnList = new List<double>();

    for (int i = 0; i < input + 1; i++)
    {
        returnList.Add(Math.Pow(2, i));
    }

    return returnList;
 }

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.GetPowersOf2(2).ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Angad just dont forget to mark at least one answer as solution and vote up on the helpfull ones as kudos for everyone who tried to help :)

Answer (score 0):

So you are aware of displaying a list in the console, as you did within the method(`returnList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);`). Now you returning the list object to the calling method and now you don't know how to display it, right? Why don't you try the same here, like this:

```
p.GetPowersOf2(2).ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Because the variable `returnList` is returning from the method, so definitely the same will receive in the calling method.

Answer (score 0):

Dont return the List and just call it like that:

```
class Program{
    public void GetPowersOf2(int input)
    {
        var returnList = new List<double>();
        for (int i = 0; i < input + 1; i++)
        {
            returnList.Add(Math.Pow(2, i));
        }
         returnList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);//display list from method.
        //return returnList;
    }
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.GetPowersOf2(2);
    }
}
```

OR return it like that:

```
class Program{
    public List<double> GetPowersOf2(int input)
    {
        var returnList = new List<double>();
        for (int i = 0; i < input + 1; i++)
        {
            returnList.Add(Math.Pow(2, i));
        }
         //returnList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);//display list from method.
        return returnList;
    }
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.GetPowersOf2(2).ForEach(Console.WriteLine);//not display list...
    }
}
```